# How to make work public variables in array?

Tags: php, arrays, var, public

Please tell me, this works great

```
$code = '111';
 $commands = [
            $code  => "тест"
    ];
```

How to make work

```
class Test {
 $code = '111';
 public $commands = [
            $code  => "тест"
    ];
}
```

Comment: It can't work like that because class variables [can only be initialised to constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) and `[
            $code  => "тест"
    ]` is not a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your class properties to be dynamic, you can do that in `__construct` which is called automatically when you create a object of the class.

```
class Test {
 public $code = '111';
 public $commands = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $this->commands[$this->code] = "тест";
    }
}

$a = new Test();
var_dump( $a );
```